# How can i align rhe values like table column in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python GUI programming. I am stuck at how to align label like table columns in python tkinter:

app.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import json
import requests
from urllib import urlopen
import os.path
import threading






top = Tk()
class myapp:
def __init__(self, parent):
    i=0
    url = "http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=get_users";
    r = requests.get(url)
    j = r.json()
    # L1 = Label(top, text='Title \n\n')
    # L1.pack( side = LEFT)
    # L2 = Label(top, text="Author \n\n")
    # L2.pack( side = LEFT)
    # L3 = Label(top, text="Body \n\n")
    # L3.pack( side = LEFT)
    for val in j:
        print val
        lb = Label(top, text=val['title'])
        lb.grid(row=i, column=1)
        #label[val['title']] = lb
        i += 1



def callfunc():
    L1 = Label(top, text="Title")
    L1.pack( side = TOP)
    E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
    E1.pack(side = TOP)

    L2 = Label(top, text="Author")
    L2.pack( side = TOP)
    E2 = Entry(top, bd =5)
    E2.pack(side = TOP)

    L3 = Label(top, text="Body")
    L3.pack( side = TOP)
    E3 = Entry(top, bd =5)
    E3.pack(side = TOP)

    data = {"author": E2.get(),
    "body" : E3.get(),
    "title" : E1.get()}
    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    url = 'http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json='
    check = connected_to_internet(url)
    if(check):
        r = requests.post(url+data_json ,headers=headers )
        if (r.status_code == 200):
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result","success")
        else:
            if(os.path.isfile("offline_post.json")):
                with open('offline_post.json','a') as f:
                    f.write(data_json+"\n")
            else:
                open('offline_post.json', 'a')
                with open('offline_post.json','a') as f:
                    f.write(data_json+"\n")
    SubmitButton = Button(text="Submit", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
                                font=("Grobold", 10), command = callfunc)
    SubmitButton.pack()

# homeButton = Button(text="Home", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
#                               font=("Grobold", 10), command = view)
# homeButton.pack()

def connected_to_internet(url, timeout=5):
    try:
        _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        threading.Timer(10, connected_to_internet(url)).start()
        print "asd"
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("No internet connection available.")
        return False

 top.title("App")
 app = myapp(top)
 top.mainloop()
```

My json looks like:

```
{"id":"1","author":"asd","title":"asdfg","body":"uihjui"}
```

Is there a seperate table like function for creating columns in python ?

Comment: how is what you want different from what you're getting? It appears you're already using the `grid` geometry manager. It would help if you could reduce this down to a very small [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mvce) that didn't rely on external data files or a custom local webserver.

Comment: but im not getting the result... I am missing something.....

Comment: what result are you not getting? What do you expect that is different from what you get? Is the data showing up in the wrong space? Is it not showing up at all?

Answer (score 0):

The button that calls "callfunc" is created in callfunc() so the button never gets created and callfunc() is never executed.  As posted in the comments, no one is sure what you want, so this is just the general idea (with the extraneous stuff omitted).  Note that local variables are garbage collected when a function exits, so E1, L1, etc. do not remain after callfunc() exits.

```
from Tkinter import *

class myapp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.row=0
        for val in ["A", "B", "C"]:
            print val
            lb = Label(top, text=val)
            lb.grid(row=self.row, column=1)
            self.row += 1

        submit_button = Button(top, text="Submit", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
                                font=("Grobold", 10), command = self.callfunc)
        submit_button.grid(row=100, column=1)

    def callfunc(self):
        for heading in ["Title", "Author", "Body"]:
            self.row += 1
            L1 = Label(top, text=heading)
            L1.grid(row=self.row, column=0)
            E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
            E1.grid(row=self.row, column=1)

top = Tk()
top.title("App")
app = myapp(top)
top.mainloop()
```